# Update BD with django backend and post form via ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-forms

Given that I have my userPersonalized model. And this has 2 fields that I want to update through a form, where they enter a numerical value and in doing so, a mathematical operation is done. Well, I want the result of that mathematical operation to update the logged-in user fields, according to the numerical value entered. I'm importing Jquery's library.

Through 2 input hidden I access the 2 fields that I want to update through the mathematical operation, which I have in my javascript file where I call it through the id

```
html file
<div><form method="POST" class="form-data" action="{% url 'solit' %}">
{% csrf_token %}
  <h6>Tipo de peticion:{{form.petit}}</h6>
  <h6>Razon:{{form.razon}}</h6>
  <h6>{{form.solicitudes_id}}</h6>
  <h6>Fecha inicio:{{form.periodo_init}}</h6>
  <h6>Fecha fin:{{form.periodo_fin}}</h6>
  <h6>Introduzca dias a tomar<input id="dias" type="number" name="dias_adicion"></h6>
  <h6>Introduzca horas a tomar<input id="horas" type="number" name="horas_adicion"></h6>
  <input type="hidden" id="const_dias" name="d_pendientes" value="{{ user.d_pendientes }}">
  <input type="hidden" id="const_horas" name="h_pendientes" value="{{ user.h_pendientes }}">
Recuerde, que usted dispone de {{ user.d_pendientes }} dias y 
{{ user.h_pendientes }} horas a compensar <br>

<button type="submit" onclick="calculo()" class="boton">Guardar</button>
```

js file ------------------------------------------------------------

```
function calculo()

{

   var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias').value);
   var horas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('horas').value);
   var dias_base  = parseInt(document.getElementById('const_dias').value);
   var horas_base  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('const_horas').value);

   dias_base -= dias;
   horas_base -= horas;

alert(dias_base);
alert(horas_base);
} console.log(calculo);
```

ajax script----------------------------------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var productForm = $(".form-data")

productForm.submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var thisForm = $(this)
  var actionEndpoint = thisForm.attr("action");
  var httpMethod = thisForm.attr("method");
  var formData = thisForm.serialize();

  $.ajax({
    url: actionEndpoint,
    method: httpMethod,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data){
      console.log("success")
      console.log(data)
    },
    error: function(erroData){
     console.log("error")
     console.log(erroData)
   }
  })

 })
})
```

and my view in django --------------------------------------

```
def solit(request):
if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
    form = addiForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        peticion = form.save()
        if peticion.usuario:
            peticion.usuario.d_pendientes = request.POST.get('d_pendientes', None)  # Get the form value if has, otherwise assign it to None (change it if you want another default value)
            peticion.usuario.h_pendientes = request.POST.get('h_pendientes', None)  # The same
            peticion.usuario.save()
            print (request.POST)

        return JsonResponse({'status': 'true', 'msg': 'Procesado Correctamente'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'msg': 'Los datos no son validos'})

form = addiForm()
return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py ------------------------------------

```
class addiForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    """Formulario de solicitud"""

    model = Peticion

    fields = [

        'solicitudes_id',
        'petit',
        'razon',
        'periodo_init',
        'periodo_fin',
        'dias_adicion',
        'horas_adicion',

    ]

    labels = {

        'solicitud_id':'Solicitud',
        'petit':'Tipo de Petición',
        'razon':'Razon',
        'periodo_init':'Rango de fecha inicial',
        'periodo_fin':'Fecha final',
        'dias_adicion':'Dias a adicionar, si es mas de 8 horas',
        'horas_adicion':'Horas a adiciona, si es menos de 1 dia',
```

models.py-------------------------------------------

```
class Usuarios(AbstractUser):
   numero_empleado = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)
   area = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
   d_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)
   h_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)
   f_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200,null= True, blank= True)
   init_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
   fin_vac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null= True, blank= True)
   ul_vac_tomadas = models.IntegerField(null= True, blank= True)


class Peticion(models.Model):
   solit_choices = (
    ('Adicionar','Adicionar'),
)
   solicitudes_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuarios, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
   petit = models.CharField(max_length = 255, choices=solit_choices, null=True, blank=False)
   fec = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   razon = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
   periodo_init = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
   periodo_fin = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
   dias_adicion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
   horas_adicion = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)
```

currently, in the javascript console when giving submit, the following message returns me {status: "true", msg: "Processed correctly"}
msg: "Processed Properly"
status: "true"
**proto**: Object, but the value does not update me 
example: I have 5 apples available, well I take 2, well I should send that 2 to the user database, but it does not. What do I want to update in the user through the mathematical operation, please help, what am I doing wrong? greetings and thanks.

Comment: Post your form please.

Comment: Hi @Hagyn ok, add it thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to update an object instance right?

Comment: @Hagyn No, I am trying to update 2 objects in this case: "d_pendientes" and "h_pendientes" of the customized model through 2 fields of the Petition model

Comment: Post the model where d_pendientes and h_ pendientes is please.

Comment: @Hagyn added it thanks for u answer

Comment: @Hagyn 
wow, I feel close and everything you've written makes sense, but it doesn't update me yet, what do you think it might be? Thank you very much for your response and sorry for the inconvenience I update, update my views.py or do you think it could be the ajax script? Because my form.html uses a js funtion to do the operation, that data from the fields, I should send in the ajax scrip, as selected by the class

Comment: Debug the code and check if the data is arriving to server-side and if your `peticion` has a `usuario` linked.

Comment: Thanks for your response again, just as a last query, do you know what a method or means is to know if the data reaches the server? because this comes to me in the django console: "POST / solit / HTTP / 1.1" 200 52

Comment: @Hagyn 
I will debug my code, but I just want to make this function work, update my view, with the "print = (request.POST)", dog does not print anything on the django console, keep sending the same code 200 that means, that The request has been accepted correctly. How would you do it in the view?

Comment: Are you sure your request is a POST one?

Comment: Ok, and if I want, to update the data without ajax, it's easier right? How would you do it in the view? Yes, it is a publication, thanks to the fact that I am seeing the traffic by wireshak and it is sending me the data, but not the result of the mathematical operation of my js file. But the data that I enter in the fields, without a hahaha field, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are supposing your Peticion form will save 2 fields of Usuarios. You will have to save that 2 fields separately, you could do it this way:

```
def solit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        form = addiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            peticion = form.save()
            if peticion.usuario:
                peticion.usuario.d_pendientes = request.POST.get('d_pendientes', None)  # Get the form value if has, otherwise assign it to None (change it if you want another default value)
                peticion.usuario.h_pendientes = request.POST.get('h_pendientes', None)  # The same
                peticion.usuario.save()
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'true', 'msg': 'Procesado Correctamente'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'false', 'msg': 'Los datos no son validos'})

   form = addiForm()
```

That should do the work, have in mind that ModelForm won't ever save vars of another model if you don't implement it.